# MVC 5 - RedirectToAction - Cannot pass parameter correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method that looks as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(int? birdRowId, Entities.BirdSighting sighting)
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

I want to call the above method from another method in the same controller as follows:

```
   [Authorize]
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(Entities.BirdSighting birdSighting, FormCollection collection)
    {
    ...
    ...

    return RedirectToAction("Create", new {birdRowId = 10, sighting = birdSighting}); 
    }
```

The RedirectToAction method calls the method correctly. And, the first parameter of the method being called (birdRowId) does equal 10. However, the second parameter, sighting, is always null, even though I'm passing an instantiated object with values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clear this bit up, but do you have a custom model binder that deals with `Entities.BirdSighting`? e.g. in global.asax.cs, is there is declaration `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Entities.BirdSighting), new FooCustomBinder());` Other people may ask about that, just in case.

Comment: No I don't. I am somewhat new to this so I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I'll try this a bit later. I need to step out for a couple hours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your RedirectToAction menthod isn't doing what you think it's doing.  You can tell by looking at the URL you are redirected to..  You will notice it says `sighting=Entities.Birdsighting`  or something similar.. which is just the class name.  You really shouldn't take complex objects as parameters in get methods, it's just not easy to deal with.  Maybe you can lookup the birdsighting via a birdsigthing id that you pass?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember, **HTTP is stateless !**

`RedirectToAction` method returns a **302** response to the client browser and thus the browser will make a new **GET** request to the specified URL.

If you are trying to follow the [**PRG**](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/) pattern, I think you should not try to pass complex objects. You should only pass the ID of the resource so that the GET action can build the resource( the model) again using that ID.

```
return RedirectToAction("Created", "YourControllerName", new { @id=10} );
```

and in the Created action, read the `id` and build the object there.

```
public ActionResult Created(int id)
{
  BirdSighting sighting=GetSightingFromIDFromSomeWhere(id);
  // to do  :Return something back here (View /JSON etc..)
}
```

If you really want to pass some data across (Stateless) HTTP Requests, you may use some temporary storage mechanism like **TempData**

Set your object to TempData in your HttpPost action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BirdSighting birdSighting, FormCollection collection)
{
 // do something useful here
  TempData["BirdSighting"] =birdSighting;
  return RedirectToAction("Created", "YourControllerName");
}
```

And in your GET action method,

```
public ActionResult Created()
{      
  var model=TempData["BirdSighting"] as BirdSighting;
  if(model!=null)
  {
     //return something
  } 
  return View("NotFound");
}
```

`TempData` uses `Session` object behind the scene to store the data. But once the data is read, the data is terminated.

Comment: Great answer - thank you. And I see you are close by. I'm in NW Ohio.

Comment: Tempdata is a bad solution for this, since if the user refreshes the page (F5) then the data is gone...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I agree. That is my first solution is to follow the PRG pattern. TempData solution is only if he does not want to pass the querystring value and build the object again.